# How to push some data from Json into new array in AngularJS?

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

Let's say I have this Json ..

```
{
    "name": "Mark",
    "gender": "male",
    "account1": {
        "accountNo": 1201,
        "balance": 300
    },
    "account2": {
        "accountNo": 1354,
        "balance": 5000
    }
}
```

What I expect is like ..

```
$scope.myArray = [
    {
        "accountNo": 1201,
        "balance": 300
    },
    {
        "accountNo": 1354,
        "balance": 5000
    }
];
```

In AngularJS, how can I pick some part of Json data  and push it into an array iteratively( I mean, when I have account1, account2 account3 or more, it can still add them into the array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could normally just assign the array over, but in this scenario that is not an option because your array is psuedo.

Ideally you would like to be able to do what this answer (related question) does: [How to return and array inside a JSON object in Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720520/how-to-return-and-array-inside-a-json-object-in-angular-js) which is simply

```
$scope.myArray = json.accounts;
```

However, as noted, you do not have an accounts array so you need to make one.

```
var accounts = [];
for(var key in json){
 if( !json.hasOwnProperty(key) // skip prototype extensions
  || !json[key].hasOwnProperty("accountNo") //skip non account objects
 ) continue; 
 accounts.push(json[key]);
}
```

And now you may use this array

```
$scope.myArray = accounts;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access Json data like an array. Like `var foo = { ... , 'bar' = 'value', ... }` you could get `foo` value by doing this `for['bar']`. So, by knowing this, you simply do something like

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr.push(foo['account'+i]);
}
```

Although, this has nothing to do with angularjs.

Comment: "Although, this has nothing to do with angularjs" is true, but all you need to do to make this answer complete from an angular perspective is to add `$scope.myArray = arr;` . Recognizing the key numbers in the object was smart, but also do note they start at 1 and not 0. And also, you would push a lot of undefined values into the array since the total number is unknown.

Comment: About the numbers and undefined, I just wrote this as an abstract example, since, as I suppose, problem described abstract itself.