# How to structure my json value that got pushed to array in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is [my punker](https://plnkr.co/edit/f0Q1NU?p=preview)

I can get the selected values pushed to array by `ngcheck` and `ngchange`, but I want to push the `{{get_ing_value.productName}}` to array when I click any of the checkbox and radio button.

This is what I have:

```
[
    {
        "selected": {
            "_id": "584aa4e218c5b62c02b6fe6a",
            "productId": "584aa4e118c5b62c02b6fe67",
            "ingredientTypeId": "5822f17b24baa627770af5ed",
            "ingredientName": "small",
            "slug": "small",
            "isActive": true,
            "ingredientPrice": -75
        }
    },
    {
        "selected": {
            "_id": "584aa4e718c5b62c02b6fe6e",
            "productId": "584aa4e118c5b62c02b6fe67",
            "ingredientTypeId": "5822f18324baa627770af5ee",
            "ingredientName": "extra cheese",
            "slug": "extra-cheese",
            "isActive": true,
            "ingredientPrice": 20
        }
    },
    {
        "selected": "{\"_id\":\"584aa4e918c5b62c02b6fe70\",\"productId\":\"584aa4e118c5b62c02b6fe67\",\"ingredientTypeId\":\"5822f19724baa627770af5ef\",\"ingredientName\":\"hot chilly\",\"slug\":\"hot-chilly\",\"isActive\":true,\"ingredientPrice\":20}"
    },
    {
        "selected": "{\"_id\":\"584aa4ea18c5b62c02b6fe71\",\"productId\":\"584aa4e118c5b62c02b6fe67\",\"ingredientTypeId\":\"5822f1a024baa627770af5f0\",\"ingredientName\":\"chicken\",\"slug\":\"chicken\",\"isActive\":true,\"ingredientPrice\":50}"
    }
]
```

This is what I want to get

```
[
    {
        "main_product_name": "PIZAA"
    },
    {
        "selected": {
            "_id": "584aa4e218c5b62c02b6fe6a",
            "productId": "584aa4e118c5b62c02b6fe67",
            "ingredientTypeId": "5822f17b24baa627770af5ed",
            "ingredientName": "small",
            "slug": "small",
            "isActive": true,
            "ingredientPrice": -75
        }
    },
    {
        "selected": {
            "_id": "584aa4e718c5b62c02b6fe6e",
            "productId": "584aa4e118c5b62c02b6fe67",
            "ingredientTypeId": "5822f18324baa627770af5ee",
            "ingredientName": "extra cheese",
            "slug": "extra-cheese",
            "isActive": true,
            "ingredientPrice": 20
        }
    },
    {
        "selected": "{\"_id\":\"584aa4e918c5b62c02b6fe70\",\"productId\":\"584aa4e118c5b62c02b6fe67\",\"ingredientTypeId\":\"5822f19724baa627770af5ef\",\"ingredientName\":\"hot chilly\",\"slug\":\"hot-chilly\",\"isActive\":true,\"ingredientPrice\":20}"
    },
    {
        "selected": "{\"_id\":\"584aa4ea18c5b62c02b6fe71\",\"productId\":\"584aa4e118c5b62c02b6fe67\",\"ingredientTypeId\":\"5822f1a024baa627770af5f0\",\"ingredientName\":\"chicken\",\"slug\":\"chicken\",\"isActive\":true,\"ingredientPrice\":50}"
    }
]
```

Comment: Plnkrs are fine for *augmenting* your question, but you'll still have to put a substantial relevant part of your code into your actual question here for it to make sense.

Comment: okay thank you for the edits

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323330/how-to-push-some-data-from-json-into-new-array-in-angularjs)?

Comment: no if i click  get selected checkbox and radio values button the only selected  values are of pushing into array instead of that i want to push that main name PIZZA to array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code, may be it helps you. It will set PIZZA as main_product_name in first index of your array when you select any radio or checkbox, it will also check if main_product_name is already added.

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

   $scope.get_product_ingredients;
   $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1gh1pl').then(function(res) {
    $scope.get_product_ingredients = res.data;
   });
  $scope.selected_ingrediants = [];
  $scope.tempCheck = {};
  $scope.formatted = [];

  $scope.get = function() {
    if(!$scope.formatted[0]){
     $scope.formatted[0] = {
      main_product_name: $scope.get_product_ingredients[0].productName
     }
   }
  };

 $scope.updateIngredient = function(type, model, index){
   if(!$scope.formatted[0]){
     $scope.formatted[0] = {
      main_product_name: $scope.get_product_ingredients[0].productName
     }
   }
   $scope.formatted[index+1] = {
     //ingredientTypeName: type,
    selected: model
   }

  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not working in my  plunker can you post plunker

Comment: exactly but if i click two values in NON-VEGETABLES means one value get disappeared

Comment: check now, updated your HTML this time :)
https://plnkr.co/edit/PfV53gicxwHLO6oG9SsK?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much can you explain

Comment: Yes, 
1. Actually you were sending a the key to the function updateIngredient(), where you used that key as index. The value of key was starting from 0 and maximum to the length of array. I just added [index+1] in this function, so that it will always take index from 1 to maximumLength+1, it means 0 index is free always. On 0 index i check if there is value or not, if not then put main_product_name there.

Comment: 2. For non-vage checkboxes you were sending key for both checkboxes, which is same(3) in both. So when you check them one is replace by other because of same index, so i added key+$index in you html part, it will give 3+0(3) and 3+1(4), So the same index issue will resolve.
Don't forget to upvote if i explained well :) thanks